# Can we derive that $A$ commutes with $B$ from this?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, matrices

Based on some Physics backgrounds, I want to confirm the following thing.

Let $[A,B]:=AB-BA$, where $A,B$ are matrices. Now the question is as follows:

If for *any* real number $\lambda$, $[A,e^{\lambda B}]=0$, then is $[A,B]=0$ true? Where $A,B$ are matrices.

If the above statement is true, how to give a **rigorous** proof ?

So far the approach by myself is: $[A,e^{\lambda B}]=\lambda[A,B]+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}[A,B^2]+...=0\Rightarrow\frac{1}{\lambda}[A,e^{\lambda B}]=[A,B]+\frac{\lambda}{2}[A,B^2]+...=0 $(for any nonzero $\lambda$), then $\lim_{ \lambda\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\lambda}[A,e^{\lambda B}]=[A,B]=0$.

Is my proof rigorous from the Math viewpoint? Other *excellent* method is **welcome**! Thanks!

Comment: By "for _any_", it seems, you mean "for all"?

Comment: Your proof is correct, once you know that power series with matrix coefficients behave in the same way as usual power series.

Comment: Are any of those matrices Unitary?

Comment: @  Daniel Fischer, yes

Comment: @  Etienne, thanks

Comment: @ Anurag Pallaprolu, any kind of matrices is allowed, not need to be *unitary*

Comment: @DanielFischer What's the difference?

Comment: @VedranŠego "For any" can mean "There exists (at least) one".

Comment: @DanielFischer That would be "for *some*", wouldn't it? "For *any*", in this context, means "[whichever of a specified class might be chosen](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/any)". Not that I insist; I just want to know if I'm wrong, so that I don't repeat the mistake.

Comment: @VedranŠego "the illness may be due to any of several causes" The problem is that "any" is ambiguous, it can mean $\forall$ or $\exists$ without violating the language. So it's better to avoid it, IMO.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, I can accept that. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$e^{\lambda B}$ is an analytic function of $\lambda$. Therefore, $$\frac{d}{d\lambda }e^{\lambda B}=Be^{\lambda B}=e^{\lambda B}B.$$
We write

$$0=\frac{d}{d\lambda }[A,e^{\lambda B}] = ABe^{\lambda B}-e^{\lambda B}BA ,$$
hence for $\lambda=0$ we obtain $[A,B]=0$.

**Previous version**
$$0=\frac{d}{d\lambda }[A,e^{\lambda B}] = Ae^{\lambda B}B-e^{\lambda B}BA =e^{\lambda B}(AB- BA),$$
hence by the fact that $ e^{\lambda B} $ is non-singular we obtain that $[A,B]=0$.

**Possible generalisation of the problem**

If $[A,e^{\lambda B}]$ is a constant matrix with respect to $\lambda$ on a non-empty interval $(\lambda_-,\lambda_+)$, then $[A,B]=0$.

**Clarification**

A matrix is called non-singular if its determinant is non-zero (i.e. the matrix is invertible or the matrix doesn't have zero eigenvalues). In our case, the eigenvalues of the matrix $e^{\lambda B}$ have the form $e^{\lambda \mu_j}\ne 0$ where $\mu_j$ are eigenvalues of $B$. The determinant of the matrix is a product of its eigenvalues taken with multiplicity, hence we can conclude that $\det e^{\lambda B}\ne 0$.

As for analyticity, I suggest you read these two articles on wiki: [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) and 
[Jordan matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix), especially functions of matrices and spectral mapping theorems.

Comment: By assumption, $e^{\lambda B}$ commutes with $A$, it also commutes with $B$, so actually, there wasn't an error.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, you are right, I'll add the previous version.

Comment: @ TZakrevskiy, excellent answer. But how to understand " $e^{\lambda B}$ is non-singular" or " $e^{\lambda B}$  is an analytic function of $\lambda $" in your answer?

Comment: @K-boy I'll edit the post to answer your comment.

Comment: @K-boy analytic function as "all components of the matrix are analytical functions of $\lambda$".

Comment: @  TZakrevskiy, thanks for your **Clarification**. So do you mean det$(e^{\lambda B})=e^{\lambda \text{tr}(B)}$ and hence is always nonzero ? Where $\text{tr}( B)$ means the *trace* of matrix $B$.

Comment: @K-boy, you are welcome. Indeed, $(e^{\lambda B})=e^{\lambda \text{tr}(B)}$ and your deduction is correct.